# How to run Longitudinal Ordinal Logistic Regression in R

Tags: r, regression, ordinal, longitudinal

I'm working with a large data set with repeated patients over multiple months with ordered outcomes on a severity scale from 1 to 5. I was able to analyze the first set of patients using the polr function to run a basic ordinal logistic regression model, but now want to analyze association across all the time points using a longitudinal ordinal logistic model. I can't seem to find any clear documentation online or on this site so far explaining which package to use and how to use it. I am also an R novice so any simple explanations would be incredibly useful. Based on some initial searching it seems like the *mixor* function might be what I need though I am not sure how it works. I found it on this site
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mixor/vignettes/mixor.pdf

Would appreciate a simple explanation of how to use this function if this is the right one, or would happily take any alternate suggestions with an explanation.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Looking at the vignette, the mixor function takes four arguments: a formula, a dataframe, an id, and a link function. Do you understand what each of these represent?

Comment: Hi Bill, I do understand the formula, dataframe, and link functions. I'm not too sure what the id argument is. Right now my data is spread across a few sheets and I'm not even sure how to best compile it into a single dataset to bring in, but if I can, I think I have an idea of what to input for the dataframe and link arguments. The formula argument was also confusing me with what they were doing with the interaction between week and drug.

Comment: Without a reproducible example, it's hard to help. But it's a good idea to work through the examples in the vignette whenever you want to understand an R package.